# MySQL failing to log in for mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use `mysqldump` in my server, from the command line.

```
root@xxxxx:/xx/xx/xx/backups/09-03-13# mysqldump db_name_xxxx --tab=. --user=xxxx 
   --password=xxxxx
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'xxxxx'@'localhost' (using 
   password: YES) when executing 'SELECT INTO OUTFILE'
```

So I assume it's a problem with username/password.

However, I can get into the MySQL command line fine using `mysql`, with exactly the same logon details.

What could be causing `mysqldump` to fail, but not `mysql`?

Comment: Nope. Your problem is that the user you are using to run the `mysqldump` does not have `SELECT` permission on the entire database. Take a look at [this](http://openconcept.ca/mysql_permissions_for_backup).

Comment: @bmorris591 That did it. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with the login details but with the user you are logging in as.

In order to carry out a mysqldump you need at least `SHOW DATABASES, SELECT, LOCK` privileges on every table in the database.  Things get more complicated if you use more exotic options such as locking etc.

[This](http://openconcept.ca/mysql_permissions_for_backup) is a faily good reference for what permissions you need for what options in mysqldump.